# Can someone explain how recursive insertion sort works?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, insertion-sort

Assuming A is an array, and n is the number of elements in A,

```
recursive_insertion_sort(A, n)
    IF n > 1 THEN
        recursive_insertion_sort(A, n-1)
        key = A[n]
        i = n - 1
        DOWHILE A[i] > key AND i > 0
            A[i+1] = A[i]
            i = i - 1
        ENDDO
        A[i+1] = temp
    ENDIF
END
```

Can someone explain how recursion works in this case? There are a few things I don't understand:

1. I don't understand why we have to call the function again if n > 1.
2. Why do we input (n-1) when we call the function again? Is it so that we start the entire process from n = 2, the first 2 elements?
3. How does recursion in general work? Like, once we call the function again, do we ignore the code from line 4 onwards, and jump straight into the second call? Or do we run the 2nd call in conjunction with the first call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before discussing the implementation, let's explain what this function does: it does not sort the entire array `A`, but only its initial `n` elements. You can pass the length of the array for `n` to sort the whole thing, but the fact that you pass the length separately is essential to understanding the rest of the answer.

> I don't understand why we have to call the function again if `n > 1`.

Perhaps a better way to explain the meaning of this condition would be that we *do not* call this function again when `n` is one or less. This is called the *base case* of recursive algorithm, i.e. the case when you don't have to do anything. In case of sorting it means that an array of only one element is already sorted.

> Why do we input `(n-1)` when we call the function again?

Since `n` is the number of elements that we need to sort, We pass `n-1` to sort the front of the array. Once the function returns, we know that the portion `A[1..n-1]` is already sorted. All we need to do is to move `A[n]` to its right place. We do that in the `DOWHILE` loop that follows: we go backward one element at a time, moving elements that are bigger than `A[n]` to the right. Once the loop is over, we place `A[n]` to its new place. Now the range `A[1..n]` is sorted.

> How does recursion in general work?

The function has two cases - the trivial base case, when everything is done, and a reduction step, when you use recursive invocation to solve a simpler problem, and then use the results of the simpler solution to construct your final solution.

> once we call the function again, do we ignore the code from line 4 onwards, and jump straight into the second call?

No, once the function returns, we continue where we left. In your case, the function waits for the `A[1..n-1]` range to be sorted before placing `A[n]` to the right place.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me and answering to all of my questions - I know I asked a lot of probably basic questions but I was really confused haha. I am able to understand the algorithm & recursion now. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 3):

Small example to understand how this works :

```
recursive_insertion_sort([1, 7, 5, 2], 4)
    | recursive_insertion_sort([1, 7, 5, 2], 3)
    |    | recursive_insertion_sort([1, 7, 5, 2], 2)
    |    |    | recursive_insertion_sort([1, 7, 5, 2], 1) 
    |    | puts 7 in the right position between it's ORDERED left values [1] -> [1,7]
    | puts 5 in the right position between it's ORDERED left values [1,7] -> [1,5,7]
puts 2 in the right position between it's ORDERED left values [1,5,7] -> [1,2,5,7]
```

Comment: I see. Writing it this way does help make it much clearer for me to understand. Thanks :)

Comment: you're welcome, it is always helpful for me to write the call tree to understand a recursion